# Execute JavaScript (HTML) file by ant and redirect output to file

Tags: javascript, html, ant

How to execute JavaScript file by ant and redirect stdout and stderr to files?
For example let say we have

helloWorld.js

```
console.log('Hello world!');
```

I need ant target to proudce

stdout.txt

```
Hello world!
```

It is acceptable to create temporary HTML file that include needed JavaScript file and then execute tmp.html, but I would like to omit this step if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) to execute Javascript from ant. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909106/ant-script-to-compile-all-css-less-files-in-a-dir-and-subdirs-with-rhino) or any of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant+rhino) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) would help with this. No HTML necessary.