# How can I include conversion from LESS to CSS in my ANT build file without including an extra Rhino .jar?

Tags: css, ant, less, rhino, build.xml

It would appear that Rhino is included in any version passed Java 6. How do I convert LESS to CSS in my build.xml file using the included Rhino capabilities of java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rhino version for less in the [dist/ folder in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/master/dist).
And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909106/ant-script-to-compile-all-css-less-files-in-a-dir-and-subdirs-with-rhino) shows how to use it in an Ant script.

Comment: I see the rhino version, but the answer you link to still depends on a rhino .jar. What changes do I need to make to it so that it doesn't need the dependency?

Comment: The only way would be a script runner wrapper class. See http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/