# Ant: Apply with fileset, but only exec once on one file?

Tags: ant, less

I'm working on something similar to the question here: [ANT script to compile all (css) LESS files in a dir and subdirs with RHINO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909106/ant-script-to-compile-all-css-less-files-in-a-dir-and-subdirs-with-rhino)

However, I'm having a hard time customizing this to one particular requirement:

- If any `.less` files in `dir.less` change: Run LESS on *just* one file (as it imports the other less files, making a single, combined output).

This is the state of my current `build.xml`:

```
<target name="less" description="Compile LESS files">

    <echo message="Checking for LESS file changes..."/>

    <apply dir="${dir.less}" executable="${tool.less}" parallel="false" failonerror="true">

        <fileset dir="${dir.less}" includes="*.less" />
        <srcfile/>

        <mapper type="glob" from="*.less" to="${dir.css}/*.css"/>
        <targetfile/>

        <arg value="-compress" />
  </apply>

</target>
```

This currently builds all of the `.LESS` files and outputs them toe the appropriate location (Which is livable). If I replace the mapper glob with:

`<mapper type="glob" from="MainFileThatImportsOthers.less" to="${dir.css}/MainFileThatImportsOthers.css"/>`

The fileset directive is effectively reduced to that one file, and changing the other `.LESS` files in that directory don't cause output from the task.

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can avoid setting this up wrong and recusing through each `.LESS` file every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution that works correctly, I used an `upToDate` task to set a property to conditionally trigger `Exec` for the compiler:

```
<target name="scanLess" description="Scan for LESS file changes">

    <echo message="Checking for LESS file changes..."/>

    <uptodate property="tool.less.changed" targetfile="${dir.css}/MyFile.css" >
        <srcfiles dir="${dir.less}" includes="*.less" />
    </uptodate>

</target>

<target name="less" depends="scanLess" unless="tool.less.changed" description="Compile LESS files" >

    <echo message="LESS files changed, running lessc" />

    <exec executable="${tool.less}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${dir.less}/MyFile.less" />
        <arg value="${dir.css}/MyFile.css" />
        <arg value="-compress" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigate how [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) work in ANT