# using less utility in ant

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

I am trying to write a target in ant to display files using the unix utility less but for some reason it keeps failing to build because of this target.  I have pasted my whole ant file below including this target.  It keeps saying this:

```
Attribute name "PlayTour.java" associated with an element type "less" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

What would be causing this? I am rather new to ant so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ant file:

```
<project>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="." destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/KnightsTour.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="PlayTour"/>
            </manifest>
                </jar>
    </target>

        <target name="view">
                <less "PlayTour.java KnightsTour.java"/>
        </target>
</project>
```

Comment: The syntax is definitely wrong on the less line - they should always be in the general format `attribute="value"`. It might be along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909106/ant-script-to-compile-all-css-less-files-in-a-dir-and-subdirs-with-rhino

Answer (score 1):

`less` isn't a valid ant task. As you've pointed out, it's a unix command.

You're probably looking for the [exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Try something like:

```
<target name="view">
    <exec executable="less">
        <arg value="PlayTour.java" />
        <arg value="KnightsTour.java" />
    </exec>
</target>
```